# API JSON em aqueduct dúvida

Tags: api, dart

Criei uma API em aqueduct inicialmente. Nela criei uma classe modelo série e dentro dela tem informações de `autor`, `ano`, `idserie` , blz aí queria criar uma classe modelo episódios ela teria o `idepsodio` ,`episodios`, `idserie`(aqui e foreign key da tabela série).

Como posso fazer para relacionar os episódios com a série?
É a primeira vez que mexo com API.

Segue abaixo o que fiz até agora:

```
class Serie extends ManagedObject<_Serie> implements _Serie{
 String get detail=>'$idserie by $autor';
}

class _Serie{
@primarykey
Int Idserie;

@Culumn()
String autor;

@Column()
Int ano;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relacionar é bem simples, é uma relação 1-para-n, na Serie tem que colocar um objeto `ManagedSet` onde depois pode usar ele para buscar os espisodios e no objeto `Episodio` coloca a classe Serie normal, com um annotations `Related` apontando para o ManagedSet da Serie.

Fica assim a classe Série:

```
class Serie extends ManagedObject<_Serie> implements _Serie{
}

class _Serie{
@primarykey
 int Idserie;
 ...
 ManagedSet<Episodio> episodiosDaSerie;
}
```

E a classe Episodio:

```
class Episodio extends ManagedObject<_Episodio> implements _Episodio{
}

class _Episodio{
@primarykey
 int IdEpisodio;
 ...
 @Related(#episodiosDaSerie)
 Serie serie;    

}
```

Comment: Certo e como eu faria um get dela ? Do da série id 1 com os episódios dela pode da um exemplo?

Comment: Tu pode ver melhor aqui https://aqueduct.io/docs/tut/executing-queries/#executing-queries

Comment: final query = Query<Episodio>(context)..where((e) => e.serie.idSerie ).equalTo( 1 )

Comment: Entendi na nos outros eu chamo série em vez de episódio na query?

Comment: não entendi o que quer dizer.

Comment: No Query<episódio>  em vez de query<Serie> seria episódio mesmo